# Query roles on a Windows machine using LDAP

Tags: ruby, windows, active-directory, ldap

Anyone know how I can write an LDAP query to determine what roles exist on a Windows machine (which may or may not be on a domain)?  I would like to do this in Ruby, although if it's only possible to do in .NET, that is a possibility.

Comment: Do you know where Roles are stored in AD?  What type of roles are you thinking of? FSMO roles?  2008 Server 'Roles'?  Something else?

Comment: I'm trying to get the local users and groups for a specific machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use LDAP to query a local machine.  You use LDAP for querying a directory on a (in the case of Windows) Active Directory Domain Controller.  I think you're probably getting your terms a bit muddled.  The most common way of querying AD from Windows goes via ADSI.  You can also use ADSI to query the local security database.  When using ADSI to query AD, you use the LDAP:// moniker.  If you want to run a query against the local security system, use the WinNT:// provider.  I haven't done this in ages but, from memory, the capitalization is significant.

I don't know ruby but perhaps this will help you search.